# svn monitor for linux

Tags: c#, git, svn, monitoring

is there any svn/git monitor for linux?

there is one written in c#
http://csharpopensource.com/svnmonitor.aspx

I would like to know when someone else have commited something to SVN right after he does it, so I can make decisions based on that.

Since I'm not the owner of the repository I can't use a post commit hook of my own.

Comment: What do you want to do when the commit occurs?  Do you just want to be notified?  Do you want to have something occur automatically?

Comment: Have you tried building and running it with mono on Linux?

Comment: @TomHennen I want the application to check repo every second (using url) and if revision has changed I want to be notife what has changed (something like svn st -u)

Answer (score 2):

Try [SVN::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.67/lib/SVN/Notify.pm) or [specto](http://specto.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Commit Monitor](http://code.google.com/p/commitmonitor/) under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) (runner of Win applications on UNIX platform) or [Subversion Commit Monitor](http://ghost.tweakblogs.net/blog/3073/subversion-repository-monitor.html) as the replacement.